Знаки препинания в предложении "что, задумай она сбежать - ничего бы не вышло"

Стража стояла так близко, что, задумай она сбежать, - у нее ничего бы
не вышло.

Скажите, пожалуйста:

Нужна ли запятая после что?
Какой знак препинания корректно поставить после сбежать?


Правильно:
Стража стояла так близко, что задумай она сбежать — у нее ничего бы не вышло.
Сравнить: Стража стояла так близко, что если бы она задумала сбежать, то у нее ничего бы не вышло.
СПП, три предикативные основы, придаточные условия и степени + следствия. Фразеологизированная конструкция в придаточном условия (это специфические конструкции разговорной речи).
Знаки должны соответствовать исходной конструкции, а там  встреча союзов, нет запятой при наличии местоимения ТО. При пропущенном местоимении ставится тире.
